# How to pass data from a modal button toggle to a modal window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a button which toggles a modal window i would like the button to get the current Model.ID of it item that the button is attached to then pass that Model.ID into the window i would like to do this without using JavaScript.

At the moment the first Model.ID out of all of them is passed in but i want the current one

To do this would i need to put the modal toggle in a form with Method GET then post the data back to a partial view inside the modal window.

HTML Code

```
<button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop2" >Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop2" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Delete</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure that you want to delete @Model.ID this action cannot be reversed
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div>
                    <form action="@Url.Action("DeleteLesson","Lesson", new{ID = Model.ID})" method="post">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you pass the Model.ID to the `button` tag?

Comment: I don't believe that i have done that yet i think that is what is might be struggling with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify some custom parameter for your button, like

```
<button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" something="@Model.ID" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop2" >Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop2" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Delete</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure that you want to delete @Model.ID this action cannot be reversed
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div>
                    <form action="@Url.Action("DeleteLesson","Lesson", new{ID = Model.ID})" method="post">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, at the event that opens the modal, you will have to find the referrer, which is the `button`. Its `something` attribute should hold your model's id.

Answer (score 0):

The data entered the input fields are extracted using the ids of the respective fields using the jQuery `val()` method. 
Next the data obtained from the input fields are concatenated into a string. This string is passed to the modal body using the `html()` method of jQuery.